# Em C/C++, para que servem as diretivas de compilação? Quando devo utilizá-las?

Tags: c, c++, preprocessador, diretivas-de-compilação

Me deparei com um código em C que utilizava uma diretiva de compilação em `#ifdef` e não entendi muito bem para que serve. Encontrei uma explicação, mas não ficou claro. Segue um exemplo de diretiva e a explicação para a qual pesquisei:

```
#ifdef <token>
/* code */
#else
/* code to include if the token is not defined */
#endif
```

> ifdef checks whether the given token has been #defined earlier in the
> file or in an included file. If so, it includes everything between it
> and the closing #else or, if no #else is present, the closing #endif.
> ifdef can be used with built-in token identifiers set by the compiler to indicate that additional functionality is available.
>
> *ifdef verifica se o token foi atribuído anteriormente através do
> define no arquivo ou incluso no mesmo. Se sim, incluirá tudo o que estiver entre #else ou, se o #else não estiver presente, no #endif.
> ifdef pode ser usado com os identificadores de built-in token definido
> pelo compilador para indicar a disponibilidade de funcionalidades
> adicionais.*

Fonte: http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/preprocessor/ifdef.html

Afinal, para que servem as diretivas de compilação? Quando devo utilizá-las? Na prática, por que elas são utilizadas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elas são processadas antes da compilação do código propriamente dito. De uma maneira geral elas instruem o compilador de algumas ações que devem ser feitas com o código.

Neste exemplo em específico a diretiva de compilação condicional vai fazer uma verificação se uma variável existe. Note que esta variável também foi criada por uma diretiva de compilação, seja no código ou entrada no momento da chamada do compilador. A variável não faz parte do código normal. É como se fosse uma outra linguagem de programação.

Ao contrário do `if` normal do código, o `#ifdef` ou `#ifndef` só pode verificar se uma variável de compilação específica existe, nada mais. O fim dele se dá com o `#endif`.

Se existir, o compilador considerará o código dentro da diretiva como apto para ser compilado, caso contrário ele será descartado e o compilador não tomará conhecimento dele. O mesmo vale para o `#else`.

Isto é muito útil para separar código que deve ser usado quando está *debugando* ou não, ou para escolher código específico para plataformas diferentes, ou escolher que partes do código devem ser incluídos no resultado final, colocando ou retirando certas características, ajudando na otimização, ou ainda tratar situações especiais.

Também é possível usar um `#if` que permite fazer uma condição mais sofisticada, ou `#else` ou `#elif`, como na linguagem "normal".

Outra diretiva muito usada é incluir outros arquivos de código dentro do código principal, especialmente arquivos de cabeçalho com declarações necessárias ao código. `#include`

Além da `#define` para definir as variáveis e macros e `#undef` para remover a definição, é bastante usado a `#pragma` para dar instruções mais específicas ao compilador, incluindo o desligamento de certos *warnings* e erros.

Existem outras menos usadas (`#line`, `#error`).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).